# Vector field flux calculation

Tags: integration, vector-fields, line-integrals, greens-theorem

> Consider the vector field:
>   $$F=((y+1)e^{y^2}\sin(y^3),0)$$
>   and the curve consisting of the three line segments $A$, $B$ and $C$. Where $A$ goes between $(1,-1)$ and $(1,1)$. $B$ goes between $(1,1)$ and $(-1,1)$ and $C$ goes between $(-1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$. Find the flux of $F$ across this curve. The direction of the normal is away from the origin.

I came upon this question while practicing. It seems relatively easy if I forget the last line, I can just parametrize the 3 segments, use the flux formula 3 times and add the 3 integrals I get. Or just finish the square and use Green's Theorem to which I subtract the line integral over segment $CB$. Does the last line change any of my calculations? I thought the normal would always face away from the origin so I don't know if I have to make any changes or if it's just a useless given.

Comment: The direction of the normal of a closed curve in the green theorem is defined as the **outer** normal which means it is directed away from region inside the curve. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So is it correct to use Green's Theorem over the square then remove *from the result the flux of CB?

Comment: I think so. Yes it is. :)